# Applescript - list all running applications

Tags: applescript

How can i get a list of running applications in the same order they appear when doing ⌘ + ⇥ from within an applescript?

I.e. if I use **TextEdit**, then **Preview**, then **iCal**, the order is

iCal, Preview, TextEdit

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945033/getting-the-list-of-running-applications-ordered-by-last-use) which asked if there was an API that could produce this list provided this answer:

$ cd /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework

$ nm LaunchServices | grep __LSCopyApplicationArrayInFrontToBackOrder

But how can I access this list from within an applescript?

Answer (score 8):

`tell application "System Events" to get name of every process`

It *looks* sorted by launch date to me, but I don't know if that's reliable or not.

As for using the answer from SO: you would have to create a small program (or OSAX) in (Objective)-C to access that routine, make the program scriptable, then call that program/OSAX from your script.

Comment: This is definitely not a list of applications sorted by command-tab. It is not even a list of apps; it's a list of low-level processes, like system events.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure as how to order them But this lists applications that are not background only

```
tell application "System Events" to get the name of every process whose background only is false
```