# NSRunningApplication, return list of recently used applications?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsworkspace, nsrunningapplication

I'm trying to get a list of the most recently used applications. `NSWorkspace` returns a list of active applications and I can sort them on a few options using `NSRunningApplication`. see list below:

```
- launchDate
- finishedLaunching
- processIdentifier
```

I don't want the launch date but the most recent 'active' date (like the way <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> sorts).
Does anyone know the solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

There is no documented way of doing this that I'm aware of, but I wrote exactly what you are asking for using private APIs: http://gist.github.com/163918

Also, see [Getting the list of running applications ordered by last use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945033/getting-the-list-of-running-applications-ordered-by-last-use) for solutions that do not use private APIs.

Comment: hi 0xced, thanks for your answer, i will look into both solutions, it looks very promising!

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this sample provided by Apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AppList/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008859-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

In this sample, they are using NSRunningApplications Class in order to get all the bundle data about running applications.