# macOS - Get the list of apps currently running, in order of recent usage

Tags: macos, cocoa

I want to get the list of apps currently running on macOS, in order of recent usage.

The built-in `cmd-tab` feature does it.

`NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications` returns the set of running apps, but not in the desired order.

As a last resort, I am open to using private api calls as well.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSRunningApplication, return list of recently used applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995543/nsrunningapplication-return-list-of-recently-used-applications)

Comment: Please don't [delete a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58050262/macos-programatically-get-all-apps-running-currently) just to repost it again. In the future, just update your original question as needed.

Comment: They've been deprecated for ages, but you might try `GetFrontProcess()` and `GetNextProcess()` to see if they return the apps in the order they're currently stacked.